# Can I export data to another react component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, reactjs

I  get the redux value make a new array in `Data.js`,and I want to use the new array data to draw a chart in `Chart.js`

so...

How can I to pass the data_pie to `Chart.js`
can I just export `data_pie` in `Data.js`?

There is a react component to get the data

```
//Chart.js

import ChartBar from './ChartBar.js';
import Data from './Data.js';

export default class Chart extends Component{   
render(){
        return
            <div className="chart">
              <ChartBar data={Data}/>
            </div>
        );   
    } }
```

And in data.js get some value from the redux

```
//Data.js
import React,{ Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import raws from './another.json';

function filter_pie(apple,lemon){
   //...put raws and redux together to filter some array we need
  }
  return [newArray,pieName]
}

class Data extends Component {
  render () {
    const { props: { apple, lemon } } = this
    let data_pie = filter_pie( apple, lemon )
    return(
      <div>
        {data_pie} //can I put the data in there ? or I don't need to write any return in this js?
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    apple:state.apple,
    lemon:state.lemon,

  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Data);
```

I have no idea how can I to pass the array `data_pie` to `chart.js`

Comment: If your `Data.js` is purely for data manipulation. Import the `Chart.js` into `Data.js` as children and send `pie_data` as `props` to chart

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja I know this method , But I want to cut up the function component and chart component clear.Do you have any great idea?thanks!

Comment: Actually, There is nothing called `function component`. Components are meant for `DOM` elements. Where these functions are implemented else where like `utils` to manipulate data. And we use these functions on `props ` before passing to `components` i.e in `reducer` level itself.

Comment: so... My logic is wrong? I can't export the data to another component , only can to use the `props` to send the data to children like you said

Comment: I think you can't export data from component unless you have an event to trigger the parent `function`. Your approach may not be proper to do this. Better go with `props` to `Chart.js`

Comment: ok !! I‘ve got it !!! thank you a lot !!!

Answer (score 1):

If data is manipulated in Data.js it should be saved to the redux store using a action and reducer.

When you stored your data to the redux store just create another container component around Chart.js and use mapStateToProps() for the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass data directly to another component, I am supposing that your reducer part is working fine and you are getting data in `data.js`, here is what your code will look like

```
//Chart.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import ChartBar from './ChartBar.js';
//import Data from './Data.js';  //No need to import here

export default class Chart extends Component{   
    static propsTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    render(){
        return
            <div className="chart">
              <ChartBar data={this.props.data}/>
            </div>
        );   
    } 
}
```

and your Data file will look like this,

```
//Data.js
import React,{ Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import raws from './another.json';

import Chart from './Chart'; //fix the path to Chart.js if that file is not in same folder.

function filter_pie(apple,lemon){
   //...put raws and redux together to filter some array we need
  }
  return [newArray,pieName]
}

class Data extends Component {
  render () {
    const { props: { apple, lemon } } = this
    let data_pie = filter_pie( apple, lemon )
    return(
      <div>
        { //data_pie}
        { //instead use <Chart /> here and pass data_pie as prop }
        <Chart data={data_pie} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    apple:state.apple,
    lemon:state.lemon,

  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Data);
```

Comment: Another way is to use redux, save `data_pie` to store and get this data on `Chart.js` but its a costly approach.